# Are Ivar and Álvaro etymologically the same?

Tags: cross-linguistic, etymology, names

I have heard that the Spanish name Álvaro is of Germanic origin. So I began wondering where it might be preserved in the Germanic languages. After some thought I came up with the Scandinavian name Ivar, which looked somehow similar.

Are the Spanish name Álvaro and the Scandinavian name Ivar etymologically related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Wiktionary for the Old Norse name [Ívarr](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%8Dvarr#Old_Norse):

> The first part (*Ív-*) stems from Proto-Germanic **īwaz* (“yew”), whence also Old English *īw*. The second part (*-arr*) stems from Proto-Germanic **harjaz* (“warrior”), whence also Old Norse *herr* (“army, crowd”). Partly merged with Old Norse *Yngvarr*, *Ingvarr*.

About [*Álvaro*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%81lvaro), the same source presents the following etymology:

> *Álvaro* and *Álvara* stem from the Late Latin proper name *Alvarus*, from Spanish-Visigothic. The Germanic proper name consists of two parts: The first part stems from **all-* ("all") or from **adal-* ("noble"). The second part stems from **-wars* ("protection, defense"). However, there exist other etymologies.

Since the name Álvaro can also be found in [Portuguese](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%81lvaro), one of these "other etymologies" is that *Alvaro* would have stemmed from *Ælfred*, related to Germanic *alfi*, "elf", *radi*, "counsel". The voicing (from [f] to [v]) could have been influenced by the Hispanic *albar*, derived from Latin *albor* (from *albus*, "white").

There is another, more far-fetched etymology: according to Meyer-Lübke, *[Romanische Namenstudien](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Romanische_Namenstudien.html?hl=pt-BR&id=6yETAAAAQAAJ)*. I, 8, 81, II, 73, the name *Álvaro* stems from *al-*, "all", and **wars*, "aware, circumspect"; another possibility for the second element is a derived form of the Gothic *warjan*. So, it would mean something like "he who is aware of everyone/everything" or "he who defends himself from everyone/everything".

It seems that the etymological evidence is quite weak and there is no consensus on the matter.